# How to convert kJ/kmole to kJ/kg?

Tags: chemistry

So say I have CO2 and a value of 50 000 kJ/kmole. This is how ive converted just want to check if im right.

so..

kJ/kmole  =  J/mole

1 mole of CO2 = 12 +16x2 = 44g

J/.044 Kg then what would I do?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above should give an explanation why. (In particular, [this link](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960) might be useful.) You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{50000\text{ kJ}}{1\text{ kmole}}\times\frac{1\text{ kmole}}{1000\text{ mole}}\times\frac{1\text{ mole}}{44.0\text{ g}}\times\frac{1000\text{ g}}{1\text{ kg}}=1136.36\text{ kJ}/\text{kg}\approx 1100\text{ kJ}/\text{kg}$$

Comment: Thankyou! So essentially its just 50000kJ/1kmole multiplied by 1 mole/44g

Comment: Yes, don't be intimidated by all the "kilos".

Comment: Yeah I see that now, thanks :)